# How do I get credit for a question I answered before registering?

Tags: support, user-accounts, unregistered-users, anonymous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Yes, a petty question. I posted an answer to a question on stackoverflow a couple weeks ago, and today registered and asked a couple questions. Both times I gave the same email address, so I'm wondering why my profile doesn't include the answer I gave.

Just curious : )

Comment: No need to do anything—I've merged them for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flag one of your posts and ask to have the accounts merged.  Or send an email to team@stackoverflow.com asking the same thing.  Sending from said email account would be ideal, but I'm sure they can figure it out given a good explanation.